# Django how can I pass data to hyperlink?

Tags: html, django, templates, hyperlink

**MY TEMPLATE**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Publication date</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for questionnaire in questionnaires %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="questionnaires" id="questionnaires" value="{{ questionnaire.id }}">
                            <label><b><a href="" >{{ questionnaire.name }}</a></b></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ questionnaire.pub_date }}</td>
                    <td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed pull-right">
            <div class="well">
                <ul class="nav ">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/teacher/questionnaires/add/" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Add new</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="single">Export to PDF</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="single">Check results</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-md" name="single">Draw charts</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Generate tokens</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Clear results</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">Delete selected</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I need to get all checked objects from checkboxes placed in table, and pass them to hyperlinks in navbar.

For example, I have hyperlink "Delete selected". I want to delete every questionnaire which is selected by clicking on that link. Is it possible? If yes how can I do that?

Comment: why don't you use django forms and formsets? read this docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/ and below there is `formsets` link

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve, 'I have hyperlink "Delete selected". I want to delete every questionnaire which is selected by clicking on that link.', it's going to require a mix of jQuery and Django.

You should attach a click listener on the 'Delete selected' button which should serialize all selected questionnaires and send that data via AJAX to a Django view which will delete the necessary questionnaire objects from the database.

Here is a rough example...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
            $.post('url/to/django/view', $('input[name=questionnaires]').serialize(), function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // DO STUFF VIA THIS CALLBACK
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

```
def url/to/django/view(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        questionnaires_to_delete = request.POST.getlist('questionnaires')
        Questionnaire.objects.filter(id__in=questionnaires_to_delete).delete()
        return HttpResponse('WHATEVER YOU WANT TO RETURN TO THE CLIENT')
```

You many run into CSRF issues depending on your setup.  Here is the documentation for handling that...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/